# Why explicitly writing the type `Product Int` works for any `Num` type?

Tags: haskell

In particular, this expression compiles:

```
x = 4 :: Product Int
```

Why does the literal `4` can be `Product Int`, even though it's type is `Num a => a` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`4` is an expression with a type annotation. The *unannotated* expression has type `Num a => a`, but the annotation forces the type to be `Product Int`.

The annotation is legal because `Product a` has a `Num` instance whenever `a` has a `Num` instance (which `Int` has):

```
> :info Product
newtype Product a = Product {getProduct :: a}
[...]
instance Num a => Num (Product a)
[...]
> Product 3 + Product 5
Product {getProduct = 8}
```

Comment: `Product` is a sub-*set* of `Num`, but `forall a. Num a => a` is a sub-*type* of `Product Int`, because the former is *less specific than* the latter: a term (like `4`) of type `Num a => a` is valid in a context (like `_ :: Product Int`) where a value of type `Product Int` is expected, but not the other way around.

Comment: @JonPurdy Aren’t subtypes usually *more* specific? I thought that is how it works in System Fsub and OOP.

Comment: @DavidYoung I got it backwards; subtyping is tricky, as are polymorphic types.

Comment: Think of all the types that have `Num` instances. `Num a => a` is not the *union* of those types, but the *intersection*. (I'm hand-waving the isomorphisms you need to make that analogy rigorous, I think. I am not a type theorist.)

Comment: Also, don't confuse *subclasses* with *subtypes*. Subclassing is one way to define a subtype, but not the only way.

Comment: @DavidYoung: Values of subtypes are more specific than values of supertypes—a record subtype typically has *more fields* than its supertype, and here, there are fewer expressions that work for any `Num` than those that work for a particular numeric type. But by “is less specific than”, I was trying to rephrase the System F subtyping relation, “is *at least* as polymorphic as”, with the same orientation as [— ≤: —], in the hope it might be clearer. Subtyping makes sense from two totally opposite directions, and I find it all too easy to get them flipped around, so I end up watching out for it.